# Icon Animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm trying to make a score line like this and i did some of functionality but it is not enough.
i'm trying to animate my icon same like in attached picture.I'm makina pk battle screen .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHcPc.jpg)

**i did some code please check this and help me if any one understand**

In thos code i made 2 text field and both takes just 3 values (i suppose these values as a score of each side and according to score the color will expand and icon will move smothly like in animations)

- 100
- 500
- 5000

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test5 extends StatefulWidget {
const Test5({super.key});

  @override
State<Test5> createState() => _Test5State();
}

class _Test5State extends State<Test5> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
int num = 1;
double scoreFirst = 0.5;
double scoreSecond = 0.5;
late Animation<double> animation;
late AnimationController controller;
double left = 0.0;
double right = 0.0;
final int timerMaxSeconds = 60;
int currentSeconds = 0;
final interval = const Duration(seconds: 1);
var giftValue = 0;
var secondGiftValue = 0;
var minGiftPrice = 100;
var giftPrice = 500;
var maxGiftPrice = 5000;

TextEditingController giftController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController giftControllerSecond = TextEditingController();

String get timerText =>
      '${((timerMaxSeconds - currentSeconds) ~/ 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}: ${((timerMaxSeconds - currentSeconds) % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';

startTimeout([int? milliseconds]) {
var duration = interval;
Timer.periodic(duration, (timer) {
setState(() {
currentSeconds = timer.tick;
if (timer.tick >= timerMaxSeconds) timer.cancel();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
void initState() {
controller = AnimationController(
duration: Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
vsync:
this);

TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
  }

  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
body: Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
children: [
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
children: <Widget>[
Icon(Icons.timer),
SizedBox(
width: 5,
              ),
Text(timerText)
            ],
          ),
SizedBox(
height: 50,
          ),
SizedBox(
height: 50,
child: Stack(
children: [
Row(
children: [
Container(
height: 20,
color: Colors.red,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * scoreFirst,
child: Text(
giftValue.toString(),
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
Container(
alignment: Alignment.topRight,
height: 20,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * scoreSecond,
color: Colors.blue,
child: Text(
secondGiftValue.toString(),
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    )

                  ],
                ),
AnimatedPositioned(
left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * left,
right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * right,
bottom: 25,
duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
child: const Icon(
Icons.accessibility,
size: 30,
color: Colors.white,
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
SizedBox(
height: 70,
          ),
ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () => startTimeout(),
child: const Text('Start'),
          ),
SizedBox(
height: 70,
          ),
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
children: [
SizedBox(
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
child: TextField(
controller: giftController,
decoration: InputDecoration(
hintText: 'Enter Value For Red',
border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                ),
              ),
SizedBox(
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
child: IconButton(
onPressed: () {
if (int.tryParse(giftController.text.trim()) ==
minGiftPrice) {
setState(() {
scoreFirst = scoreFirst + 0.1;
scoreSecond = scoreSecond - 0.1;
if (right >= 0.2) {
right = right - 0.2;
else {
left = left + 0.2;
                            }
giftValue = giftValue +
int.parse(giftController.text.trim());
log("score First:${scoreFirst.toString()}");
log("score second:${scoreSecond.toString()}");
log("left:$left");
giftController.clear();
                          });
                        }
if (int.tryParse(giftController.text.trim()) ==
giftPrice) {
setState(() {
scoreFirst = scoreFirst + (0.2);
scoreSecond = scoreSecond - (0.2);
if (right >= 0.3) {
right = right - 0.3;
else {
left = left + 0.3;
                            }
giftValue = giftValue +
int.parse(giftController.text.trim());
log("score First:${scoreFirst.toString()}");
log("score second:${scoreSecond.toString()}");
log("left:$left");
giftController.clear();
                          });
                        }
if (int.tryParse(giftController.text.trim()) ==
maxGiftPrice) {
setState(() {
scoreSecond = scoreSecond - 0.4;
scoreFirst = scoreFirst + 0.4;

if (right >= 0.5) {
right = right - 0.5;
else {
left = left + 0.5;
                            }
giftValue = giftValue +
int.parse(giftController.text.trim());
log("score First:${scoreFirst.toString()}");
log("score second:${scoreSecond.toString()}");
log("left:$left");
giftController.clear();
                          });
                        }
                      },
icon: Icon(Icons.send)))
            ],
          ),
SizedBox(
height: 70,
          ),
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
children: [
SizedBox(
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
child: TextField(
controller: giftControllerSecond,
decoration: InputDecoration(
hintText: 'Enter Value For Blue',
border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                ),
              ),
SizedBox(
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
child: IconButton(
onPressed: () {
if (int.tryParse(giftControllerSecond.text.trim()) ==
minGiftPrice) {
setState(() {
scoreFirst = scoreFirst - 0.1;
scoreSecond = scoreSecond + 0.1;

if (left >= 0.2) {
left = left - 0.2;
else {
right = right + 0.2;
                            }
secondGiftValue = secondGiftValue +
int.parse(giftControllerSecond.text.trim());
log("score First:${scoreFirst.toString()}");
log("score second:${scoreSecond.toString()}");
log("left:$left");
giftControllerSecond.clear();
                          });
                        }
if (int.tryParse(giftControllerSecond.text.trim()) ==
giftPrice) {
setState(() {
scoreSecond = scoreSecond + 0.2;
scoreFirst = scoreFirst - 0.2;

if (left >= 0.3) {
left = left - 0.3;
else {
right = right + 0.3;
                            }
secondGiftValue = secondGiftValue +
int.parse(giftControllerSecond.text.trim());
log("score First:${scoreFirst.toString()}");
log("score second:${scoreSecond.toString()}");
log("left:$left");
giftControllerSecond.clear();
                          });
                        }
if (int.tryParse(giftControllerSecond.text.trim()) ==
maxGiftPrice) {
setState(() {
scoreFirst = scoreFirst - 0.4;
scoreSecond = scoreSecond + 0.4;
if (left >= 0.5) {
left = left - 0.5;
else {
right = right + 0.5;
                            }
secondGiftValue = secondGiftValue +
int.parse(giftControllerSecond.text.trim());
log("score First:${scoreFirst.toString()}");
log("score second:${scoreSecond.toString()}");
log("left:$left");
giftControllerSecond.clear();
                          });
                        }
                      },
icon: Icon(Icons.send)))
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```